# Convert array of object to an object in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a following JSON structure:

```
{"actions":[
        {"parameters":[
            {"name":"ISSUE_NUM","value":"11574"}
        ]},
        {"causes":[
           {"shortDescription":"Started by remote host 127.0.0.1"
        }], 
        //[...]
  }],
  //[...]
}
```

Is there a simple way to convert above to object like (replace unnecessary arrays to objects):

```
{"actions":{
        "parameters":{"name":"ISSUE_NUM","value":"11574"},
        "causes":{"shortDescription":"Started by remote host 127.0.0.1"}, 
        //[...]
  }},
  //[...]
}
```

Comment: How do you handle duplicates?

Comment: `{"parameters": {"name":"ISSUE_NUM","value":"11574"}}` is possible, but `{"parameters":{{"name":"ISSUE_NUM","value":"11574"}}}` is not.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Just post the link and a text like "Possible Duplicate <your link>" or use a flag

Comment: Yes it's possible. Just use a loop. Have you tried?

Comment: JavaScript won't parse this.

Comment: @Dwza... I have a JavaScript gold badge, I can singlehandedly close duplicates. That's not what I meant, I meant what to do when he has the same key twice in the array...

Comment: Is the problem always with an extra exterior Array? Do you ever want to keep arrays? Do you have arrays that have multiple objects in them?

Comment: @SecondRikudo muahhahaha... sorry :D i really got this SOOOOO wrog. hahahah... but funny :D

Comment: I smell a recursive function that tests if an array contains only one object, if so convert if not leave :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```
function transform(o) {
  if (typeof o !== 'object') { return o; }
  for (var k in o) {
    if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
      var arr = o[k];
      o[k] = {};
      for (var i in arr) {
        for (var j in Object.keys(arr[i])) {
          var kk = Object.keys(arr[i])[j];
          o[k][kk] = arr[i][kk];
        }
      }
      o[k] = transform(o[k]);
    }
  }
  return o;
}
```

I feel like I just did your homework. Next time try to show us you've tried (or pretend you did). If you want to handle duplicate keys in some way, that's left as an exercise.

Comment: I just finished my example when I come back to this question to see you posted it 5 sec faster. It's 90% like mine, so, won't post a duplicate xD. +1 anyway